# How to generate a JWT with ES256 algorithm using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwt

I am using this Github library(https://cocoapods.org/pods/JWT) to create tokens using JWT ES256.

I need to call the App Store Connect API(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi) from Objective C code for the I need to pass the JWT token(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests) encoded with ES256.

in JWT need to pass the header and payload like below.
header

```
{
"alg": "ES256",
"kid": "2X9R4HXF34",
"typ": "JWT"
}
```

Payload

```
{
"iss": "57246542-96fe-1a63-e053-0824d011072a",
"iat": 1528407600,
"exp": 1528408800,
"aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",
"scope": [
    "GET /v1/apps?filter[platform]=IOS"
]
}
```

I followed the instructions and create the API key from the app store connect and download the Authkey_xxxxx.p8 key and issuer id
(ref: https://docs.appcircle.io/account/adding-an-app-store-connect-api-key/)

I am able to create a token using the ruby function and get the token. I want to generate the same token using Objective C code

Here is the ruby code:

```
require "base64"
require "jwt"

ISSUER_ID = "69a6de83-fcea-47e3-e053-xxxxxxxxx"
KEY_ID = "JUV7......"

PATH = "/Users/user/Documents/AuthKey/AuthKey_JUVxxxxx.p8"

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read(PATH))

token = JWT.encode(
   {    iss: ISSUER_ID,
        exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
        aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
   },
    private_key,
    "ES256",
    header_fields={
    kid: KEY_ID }
    )

   puts token
```

I tried using the Objective-C code mentioned in the library but got an error.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AuthKey_JUVxxxxx" ofType:@"p8"];
NSData *content = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
SecKeyRef privateKeyString = (__bridge SecKeyRef)(content);
 
NSDictionary *payload = @{ @"iss" : @"69a6de83-fcea-47e3-e053-xxxxxxx",
                          @"exp" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInterVal],
                          @"aud" : @"appstoreconnect-v1"
               };
NSDictionary *headers = @{@"kid":@"JUV7xxxxxx"};
// Note: We should pass type of key. Default type is RSA.
NSDictionary *parameters = @{JWTCryptoKey.parametersKeyBuilder : 
JWTCryptoKeyBuilder.new.keyTypeEC};

 id <JWTCryptoKeyProtocol> privateKey = [[JWTCryptoKeyPrivate alloc] initWithSecKeyRef: privateKeyString];
id <JWTCryptoKeyProtocol> publicKey = [[JWTCryptoKeyPublic alloc] initWithSecKeyRef: privateKeyString];

id <JWTAlgorithmDataHolderProtocol> holder = [JWTAlgorithmRSFamilyDataHolder new].signKey(privateKey).algorithmName(JWTAlgorithmNameES256);

JWTCodingResultType *result = [JWTEncodingBuilder encodePayload:payload].headers(headers).addHolder(holder).result;
  NSString *encodedToken = result.successResult.encoded;
   if (result.successResult) {
      // handle encoded result
     NSLog(@"encoded result: %@", result.successResult.encoded);
   }
   else {
      // handle error
      NSLog(@"encode failed, error: %@", 
     result.errorResult.error);
   }
 }
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: *no success.* - this is not a useful problem description. Please edit your question to add more details about the problem.

Comment: *but got an error* - see my comment above...

Comment: I think the problem is the private key will be empty. I think `JWTCryptoKeyBuilder.new.keyTypeEC` is not `ES256`. Seems iOS doesn't support `ES256`.